# Why can't I construct an std::istream_iterator with an unnamed temporary?

Tags: c++, constructor, istream-iterator

g++ allows this construction of an istream_iterator from an ifstream instance:

```
std::ifstream ifstr("test.txt");
std::istream_iterator<std::string> iter1(ifstr);
```

...but it doesn't allow the same construction with an unnamed temporary:

```
std::istream_iterator<std::string> iter2(std::ifstream("test.txt"));
```

This gives:

error: no matching function for call to ‘std::istream_iterator, ptrdiff_t>::istream_iterator(std::ifstream)’

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?  - thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't, because `istream_iterator`'s constructor parameter is a non-const reference, but you provide a temporary. You cannot provide temporaries (that are rvalues) to non-const references.

But aside, even if it would take a const reference, it would still not work, because `ifstream` is not copyable. Curiously, C++ requires an accessible copy constructor to bind an rvalue to a non-const reference.

Comment: And then again, if that was allowed you would be creating an iterator to an already destroyed ifstream, and that would UB

Answer (score 2):

The stream is passed by non-const reference, but a temporary can only be passed by const-reference.

Streams are essentially always passed by non-const reference, because almost anything you do with a stream can/will modify the stream's state.